# Can two replica sets share the same database?

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I currently have 2 physical servers and one arbiter configured as a replica set. I would like to try sharing with this configuration. I know it is possible to run two mongod instances on the same server, one as master of replica 1, the other as slave of replica 2: can these two processes (master of replica 1 and slave of replica 2) point to the same database? Isn't there the danger of a sort of loop?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I am unsure if you know what replication really is.

All members in the replica set will share the same database(s), they will replicate the database(s) between them and maintain them.

Replicas are exactly that, they are copies of each other, including database.

I suggest you read: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/

#### Edit

There could be another meaning here as in to the same files since you mention running the master and slaves on the same node.

First off running two replicas on the same node is pointless. You will get no benefit and if anything you will get a performance problem since that IO is now taking double the strain it normally would.

So I would begin by saying that your idea would be really bad design even if it was feasible which it is not, the physical files cannot have multiple file locks on them.